# One-one correspondence between english words and their Gödel-numbered resultants?

Tags: logic

I have asked and known that one-one correspondence is between sentences (of PM) and Gödel numbers. I am wondering immediately that, if we number the english alphabets $a, b, \dots, z$ by $1, 2, \dots, 26$ and assign to each english word a number in the way as Gödel does, for example the word ''cab'' will have the number $2^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2$, then do we have again one-one correspondence between english words and their thus numbered resultants ? Can this be demonstrated by extant methods?

Comment: Sure, Unique Factorization Theorem.

Comment: "Godel number" isn't a thing, separate from a "numbering." So, what you have described is a numbering of the words in the English language. It doesn't really make sense to say "do we have again 1-1 correspodence between english words and Godel numbers," because a number is never a "Godel number."

Comment: Ah thank you so much for your interest. I shall rephrase my question.

Comment: So [Führerdiskriminantenproduktformel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BChrerdiskriminantenproduktformel) is an english word?

Comment: It is accurate to say this is a Godel numbering of the words in the English language, however.

Comment: That wouldn't be encodable in this scheme because "ü" is not included in his set of letters :) Indeed, neither would Gödel. :) @NikolajK

Comment: The analogy is that Gödel numbers get assigned to all sorts of things (strings of symbols, strings of strings...).  What makes the assignment useful is that one can prove which Gödel numbers correspond to well-formed formulas (or to valid proofs), not that only these nice things have Gödel numbers (in a given numbering scheme).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way every word gets a unique Gödel number -- but it is not a one-one correspondence, because there are numbers that are not the Gödel number of any words. For example, $3$ or $2^{27}$ are not the Gödel numbers of any string of symbols from your alphabet.

Of course, if you define a "Gödel number" to mean, specifically a number that his the encoding of an English word, then the correspondence *is* one-to-one. But one usually doesn't do this; "being a Gödel number" is not often considered a meaningful property of a number. The relevant property is the *relation* between the number and the thing it is a Gödel number **of**.

(The problem of defining rigorously what it means for a string of letters to be an "English word" is more or less orthogonal to this).

This situation is not different from the usual arithmetization of *logical* formulae. We define Gödel numbers for every string of symbols, but not every string of symbols is a well-formed formula (much less a sentence), so the numbering doesn't provide us a bijective correspondence between sentences and numbers.

Comment: String which is not a proper word will be a name of a child of a celebrity at some point. And that includes the name "Ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" (that's $40$ F's).